# Visual Studio 2017 path issue while installing tensorflow in Anaconda

Tags: visual-studio, tensorflow, anaconda, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

[The exact error that I get when I try to run the environment after attempting to install Keras/ TensorFlow via the Anaconda prompt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXwvF.jpg)

I am unable to install Keras or TensorFlow using Anaconda anymore. Even activating the environment results in a couple of errors as shown above. I have tried installing the Visual studio build tools 2019 (and 2017 using the community Visual Studio setup). Please advise on what I could try next to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install `Anaconda` and which `OS` are you using?

It seems `Anaconda` has not installed properly in your system. Uninstall and remove the previous `Anaconda` from your system and try reinstalling the `Anaconda`.

You can follow [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) reference to install `Anaconda` and `Tensorflow` in your system.

Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_visual_c_build_tools_2019) to install `Visual studio`.